# How can I exclude certain 'columns' from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Hopefully this is pretty simple to solve (I'm pretty new to this). I have a dataset of different regions. Here is a sample

```
Name                 Customers     Online Customers
Brandon Park         57            43
Heritage             29            20
Between the Hills    33            12
...
```

This is stored in a list of tuples (i.e., 
`[(Brandon Park, 57, 43), (Heritage, 29, 20), ...]`

I want to have a list of tuples that excluded the Online Customers section, so that my list of tuples becomes `[(Brandon Park, 57), (Heritage, 29), ...]` (notice there are only two entries in each tuple now).

I've tried various things, but none of them are getting me to the correct answer (many errors)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the last column in a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [('Brandon Park', 57, 43), ('Heritage', 29, 20)]
>>> [(name, customer) for name, customer, online_customer in l]
[('Brandon Park', 57), ('Heritage', 29)]
```

As you can see the last column `online_customer` is not included in the final result, and new tuples with `(name, customer)` are only included.